# How can I merge Hotmail accounts?

Tags: outlook.com

Is there a way to merge Hotmail accounts so that other email addresses will be aliases to the main one‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oaccount-omyinfo/renamemerge-a-hotmail-and-a-outlook-account/1e0818b0-3107-40ee-ac2b-c6ad85de3ebe

Linking is also not available any more.